# Finding Cumulative distribution function of $f_x(X) = \frac{1}{4} \cdot |X|$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, density-function

> Let $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{4}\cdot |X|$ a probability density function.
>
> $-2<X<2$;
>
> Find the Cumulative distribution function of $f_X(x)$.

What I thought was the answer is $F_X = \frac{1}2 + \frac{x}8$. Since a CDF is a function which tells us the probability of a $P(X<a)$, given certain.

Drawing the PDF generats a graph of a symetric function, which gives us a probability of a least $\frac{1}2$.

However I found out it is $F_x = P\left\{X\le x\right\}=\frac{1}2-\frac{1}2\cdot |x|\cdot |\frac{x}4|= \frac{1}2 - \frac{x^2}8$, for $-2 < x < 0$.

I can't understand why.

Comment: We have $P(X\le x) =\int_{-2}^x \frac{1}{4}|t|\, dt $ if $x\in (-2,2)$. Did you try using this? This probability is only at least $1/2$ if $x\ge 0$. To compute this integral, you can try doing it by cases of $x < 0$ and $x \ge 0$ (for $x\in (-2,2)$).

Comment: Do you mean it is $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{x^2}{8}$ for $0 < x < 2$?

Comment: @Infiaria Yes, it is. Thank you.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth
Got it to work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the help above, I made it -

I will show the answer for the interval $-2 < x < 0$. The other one is symetric.

$$\int_{-2}^{x} \frac{1}{4}\cdot |t| dt = \int_{-2}^{x} \frac{1}{4}\cdot (-t) dt $$ (since t is negative).
$$=\frac{1}4\cdot \int_{-2}^x (t) dt =- \frac{1}4\cdot \frac{t^2}2|_{-2}^{x}=-\frac{1}4\cdot \left( \frac{x^2}2\ - 2 \right)   =\frac{1}2 - \frac{x^2}{8} $$.

So at the end we get -

$${F_x} = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}0&{X <  - 2}\\\begin{array}{l}\frac{1}{2} - \frac{{{x^2}}}{8}\\\frac{1}{2} + \frac{{{x^2}}}{8}\\1\end{array}&\begin{array}{l} - 2 < x < 0\\0 < x < 2\\x > 2\end{array}\end{array}} \right.
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbdfgBPj
% MCPbqedmvETj2BSbqefm0B1jxALjhiov2DaerbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1B
% TfMBaebbnrfifHhDYfgasaacH8srps0lbbf9q8WrFfeuY-Hhbbf9v8
% qqaqFr0xc9pk0xbba9q8WqFfea0-yr0RYxir-Jbba9q8aq0-yq-He9
% q8qqQ8frFve9Fve9Ff0dmeaabaqaciGacaGaaeqabaWaaqaafaaake
% aaqaaaaaaaaaWdbiaadAeapaWaaSbaaSqaa8qacaWG4baapaqabaGc
% peGaeyypa0Zaaiqaa8aabaqbaeaabiGaaaqaaiaaicdaaeaacaWGyb
% GaeyipaWJaeyOeI0IaaGOmaaabaeqabaWaaSaaaeaacaaIXaaabaGa
% aGOmaaaacqGHsisldaWcaaqaaiaadIhadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaa
% aakeaacaaI4aaaaaqaamaalaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiaaikdaaaGaey4k
% aSYaaSaaaeaacaWG4bWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaaGcbaGaaGioaa
% aaaeaacaaIXaaaaqaabeqaaiabgkHiTiaaikdacqGH8aapcaWG4bGa
% eyipaWJaaGimaaqaaiaaicdacqGH8aapcaWG4bGaeyipaWJaaGOmaa
% qaaiaadIhacqGH+aGpcaaIYaaaaaaapeGaay5Eaaaaaa!5984!
$$